# cron job for updating user profile data imported via facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook, cron, profile

I want to write a cron job for updating user profile data on my website that I pull for users that register via facebook connect on my website.

The objective is to keep their profile data on my website in sync with their profile data on facebook. So if a user updates their profile picture on facebook. I want to update his profile picture on my website as well via a cron job which will run every 24 hours.

I wanted to know if this is possible and secondly if this is in violation of facebook privacy policy.

Based on my research it seems doable but I wanted to know if anyone has already done something like this before. It would really help.

Comment: why do you save all their info in your database first anyways? You can easily request user data from facebook every time any1 watches it...

Answer (score 0):

You can instead subscribe to "Real Time Updates" which will get Facebook to push a notification of any changes to your app - providing you have suitable permissions to access this data offline, you can then run a script to retrieve the new data immediately, or set a flag to retrieve this new info the next time the user logs in (and you have an active access token)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/